# Django shows an error after close IE10

Tags: django, internet-explorer, session, session-cookies

I'm getting this error below after set  SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE = True on my settings.py. I can open and login and logout with no errors...but if I close before login I get this error. Is there a way to fix it?
Thanks in advance!

```
----------------------------------------
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 63792)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Python27\lib\SocketServer.py", line 582, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "c:\Python27\lib\SocketServer.py", line 323, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 150
, in __init__
    super(WSGIRequestHandler, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\Python27\lib\SocketServer.py", line 638, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "c:\Python27\lib\wsgiref\simple_server.py", line 116, in handle
    self.raw_requestline = self.rfile.readline()
  File "c:\Python27\lib\socket.py", line 447, in readline
    data = self._sock.recv(self._rbufsize)
error: [Errno 10054] An existing connection was cancelled by the remote host
----------------------------------------
```

Comment: Sorry...I didn't realise that! The error is error: Errno[10054] "An existent connection was cancelled by the remote host"

Comment: Your connection is still processing but because you automatically close it before logging out you will get that error. Unexpected cancellation while the connection is still running.

Comment: Should I just ignore the error? Just a bruteforced socket closed connection?

Comment: I also got that error but I ignored it as long as my app is working fine :)